# Test Convex Hull of Vectors

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

My mathematical background is generally not so great so please pardon me if my question appears silly. I am trying to test the convex hull of 3 vectors for an intersection with coordinate axes as attached: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8m0R.jpg

I have researched literature online but nothing is really specific as to this sort of problem. If you have any references or insightful approach as to how I can solve this, I would appreciate your help.

Thanks!

Comment: Your link asks for a password

Comment: Oops, please use this link: http://imgur.com/yXbBc4w I've changed it in the original post as well. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer. It is a trivial one. Map the first two coordinates to the y-z plane and you find the line that connects eta1, eta2 since their x-components are zero. Then map the eta3 vertex to the xyz plane and interconnect the three points. It then becomes easy to see that K crosses the three planes. Cheers! –